# Validation using joi with external schema

Tags: javascript, validation, object, joi

So, i'm trying to validate if a field is required given a specific scenario.
Like this:

```
cake: Joi.object().keys({
            flavor: Joi.string().max(45).required(),
            price: Joi.string().length(2).required(),
            topping: Joi.string().length(2).required()
})
```

and in the same schema i have:

```
authentication: Joi.object().keys({
      password: Joi.string().max(45).required(),
      login64: Joi.string().max(45).required()
})
```

and i want to make a validation like:

```
authentication: Joi.object().keys({
      password: Joi.string().max(45).required(),
      login64: Joi.string().max(45).when('cake.flavor', {
      is: 'chocolate',
      then: Joi.required()
```

}
})

i want to  make login64 required if the flavor of the cake is chocolate. But nothing seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

A Joy [reference](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0#relative-references) is by default relative to the parent of the current value, which in your case is `authentication`. You need to move a couple of levels up (`...`) in order to reach `cake`:

```
login64: Joi.string().max(45).when('...cake.flavor', {
    is: 'chocolate',
    then: Joi.required()
})
```

Comment: Perfect! It solved my problem! Thanks!

Comment: @actsleazy Please consider accepting the answer